# Does Google Chrome Frame add CSS3 capabilities to IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, google-chrome-frame

Does Google Chrome Frame add CSS3 capabilities as well to IE ?

One of our clients uses IE6/IE7 in their company . So we advised them to install Chrome Frame on their systems - so that the browsers meet standards .

So now the question is -

Is [ IE + Chrome Frame ] ~ [Chrome ] ?

Can I assume that anything that works on Chrome [ say CSS3] will work on [ IE + Chrome Frame ] ?

If not what are the elements of Google Chrome Frame that do not get passed on to IE via Chrome Frame ?

Coming back to the main Question, Will CSS3 work on IE6+ Chrome Frame ?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that IE will only use the Chrome Frame rendering engine when the site has the specific meta tag that triggers it. Any site that doesn't have that meta tag will still be rendered using the standard IE6/7 rendering engine. It's often better to just install Google Chrome and use it alongside IE6/7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will replace the rendering with chromes webkit.

> Google Chrome Frame seamlessly enhances your browsing experience in Internet Explorer. It displays Google Chrome Frame enabled sites using Google Chrome’s rendering technology, giving you access to the latest HTML5 features as well as Google Chrome’s performance and security features without in any way interrupting your usual browser usage.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq

They don't mention CSS3, but that one belongs under HTML5 in googles terms.

I would not count on every feature being in Google Chrome Frame, as they might be a little behind Google Chrome.

Comment: Chrome Frame supports HTML 5 features like canvas. WebM, <video>, <audio>, WebGL, **CSS animations**, WebSockets on the same lines as Chrome.  It includes CSS3 .  

But beware of the fact that IE will break for many extensions while it's using Chrome Frame

Comment: @ngen  -  "IE will break for many extensions" . What kind of extensions ? Example ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, while I know this is true. Do you have a source for this? I would like to include it.

Comment: I think I found something . This link lists the differences between Chrome and Chrome Frame - http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/differences-between-chrome-and-chrome-frame

Comment: @mad.geek  Almost all extensions which depend on DOM of IE.

[Refer here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/differences-between-chrome-and-chrome-frame#TOC-IE-Extensions-Addons)